# Sharing folders on SharePoint and variance between "Shared with" and "Advanced"

Tags: permissions, security, folder, share

Is there a reason that when I click on a folder in SharePoint that I can see a list of people that the folder is shared with that differs from the list I see when I click on Advanced?

For example, I click on the "..." next to the folder and then click on the link where it says "Shared with lots of people" and a list of maybe 15 people show up... but when I click "Advanced" a list of only 2 people show up.

Answer (score 4):

'Shared With' contains permissions inherited from parent sites, SharePoint Groups, and AD Groups that have access.  When you click advanced, it will show these groups and individual users that have access but won't show you who is in the group or who has inherited access via a parent site.

Comment: Thanks James.  It confuses people when they see the folder is "shared with" person a, person b, person c and person d when in actuality (i.e. under advanced), it's only shared with person a.  What's the best way to explain the reasoning for showing person b/c/d when they don't actually have permission to view that file/folder?

Comment: I did not understand that part of your problem.  Could you add some screenshots and call out who is in Shared With but not in advanced?  Also has the list broken permissions inheritance?